# Is it possible to annotate my embedded Google Document?

Tags: javascript, annotations, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I would like to place my google documents into my website that consumes 7 column widths. The remaining 5 column widths would be used to display my annotations that I have for certain phrases, key points and concepts contained in my Google Document. The phrases, key points and concepts I would like to annotate should be synced with my annotation list in the right sidebar.

Is it possible to achieve this?

FYI, I am using Mozilla's Popcorn.JS to annotate YouTube Videos. [This link](http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-docs/plugins/) leads to the popcorn page.